# Preconditions for SpEL DoS vulnerability CVE-2022-22950?

Tags: spring, spring-el, denial-of-service, cve

I'm a little confused about [CVE-2022-22950](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-22950) and [the corresponding Spring advisory](https://tanzu.vmware.com/security/cve-2022-22950). The latter says that the vulnerability can be exploited through:

> [...] specially crafted SpEL expression [...]

However, an application that allows users to craft SpEL expressions, allows these users to do pretty much anything. Including code injection, which has full impact on confidentiality, integrity, and availability. Plenty of other DoS opportunities here. Take this SpEL snippet for example, which executes the `pwd` command:

```
T(java.lang.Runtime).getRuntime().exec("pwd")
```

This command is fairly harmless, but it could be substituted with anything! Now, SpEL supports different [EvaluationContexts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#expressions-evaluation-context) which can be used to restrict what is allowed in a SpEL expression. E.g. the `SimpleEvaluationContext` forbids type expressions, like the one in the above SpEL snippet.

This leads me to 2 sets of questions:

- **Is `CVE-2022-22950` even relevant for applications that use an unrestricted `EvaluationContext` for tainted SpEL expressions?**

  E.g. applications that trust selected users (like admins) enough to allow them executing arbitrary code? Or, ideally, have additional sand-boxing measures in place?

  It seems that in such scenarios (questionable as they may be) this DoS vulnerability does not add anything new to the game. Would it make sense to improve the security advisory and warn against processing user-controlled SpEL code in a permissive `EvaluationContext`?
- **Does `CVE-2022-22950` really require a "specially crafted SpEL expression"?**

  Or could an attacker exploit this DoS vulnerability by crafting data that will be processed by an otherwise harmless SpEL expression? E.g. sending a long list of query parameters to a web application that processes them using a hard-coded SpEL expression?

  When I look at the [code changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/83ac65915871067c39a4fb255e0d484c785c0c11) it seems that  crafting the data might be enough? If so, the wording of the security advisory should be adjusted!

Comment: I *think* [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/90cfde985ef08e8372ffefda2156f8091f65efe6) is the patch for the CVE you linked and yes, it seems like one needs to be able to run arbitrary SpEL to exploit that, causing an OOM error (from a seemingly harmless expression).

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimSauer. But should't this be an answer rather than a comment?

Fyi, the commit that you mentioned is very similar to the one that I've already posted in the question. The two just fix the problem on different branches, "5.2.x" and "main" respectively.

Comment: I'm not confident enough about the correctness of my information and if it actually answers your question ;-) If it does, feel free to post the equivalent as an answer and self-accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the original advisory (translated from Chinese) - https://4ra1n.love/post/Xrym_ZDj3/

It looks like exploiting this does require evaluation of arbitrary SpEL expressions. However - it allows for DoS even when using the `SimpleEvaluationContext` which is normally considered safe (or at least safer than `EvaluationContext`) and for example doesn't allow for RCE even when evaluating an arbitrary expression. But with this vulnerability, it will allow for a DoS.

The vulnerable code shown in the advisory -

```
SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expr = parser.parseExpression("new int[1024*1024*1024][2]");
SimpleEvaluationContext context = SimpleEvaluationContext.forReadOnlyDataBinding().build();
expr.getValue(context);
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't even aware of that original advisory, because NVD does not list it at [CVE-2022-22950](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-22950).
But indeed, it answers my two questions. Let me paraphrase:
1. This CVE is only relevant for applications that use SimpleEvaluationContext. Other evaluation contexts are free-for-all anyway. DoS, RCE, you name it.
2. To exploit this CVE, an attacker must be able to inject snippets of SpEL code. Injecting data that will be processed by an existing SpEL expression will generally not be enough to cause DoS.

Comment: Hi @meeque Can you please confirm that this vulnerability is not a threat if SimpleEvaluationContext is not used.  In our application we do not use SpEL. Should we upgrade based on this vulnerability? ( I know its best to upgrade anyway but I am trying to prioritize the workload)

Comment: Hi @IshanHettiarachchi. It's been a while, and I do not remember all the details. But the statement "this vulnerability is not a threat if SimpleEvaluationContext is not used" is kinda dangerous. Any implementation of SpEL EvaluationContext could be dangerous. In fact, most of them are vulnerable by design.
That said, if you do not use SpEL at all, you should be fine.

Comment: @meeque Thanks. We decide to upgrade the libraries.